# How to Perform String Lookups in Automapper Based on Destination Property Name?

Tags: c#, lambda, automapper

I'd like to generalize a property lookup from code like this

```
.ForMember(dest => dest.FirstName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue("FirstName"))
.ForMember(dest => dest.LastName, opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue("LastName"))
... (repeated for many properties)
```

to a one-liner, conceptually something like this:

```
// How can I access the property name?
.ForAllMembers(opt => opt.MapFrom(src => src.GetValue([[PROPERTYNAME]]))
```

The "source" value is almost always be a string-based lookup into a GetValue() method, using the property name from the destination.  I just don't know how to access the string name of the property from the "source" lambda when it's defined in the "destination" lambda.  It seems like there ought to be a way to do this but I'm not having luck finding a relevant example.

I hope this makes sense.  Thanks in advance for any insights,

Jeff

Comment: Can you clarify the signature of the .ForMember() method?
Also, do you already know the list of properties for which you would like to perform this lookup at the point you call the method, or do you need to reflect the type to get a list of properties with getters?

Comment: could you give an example of the classes that you want to map

Comment: it could be that ValueInjecter is the type of mapper that you need if you want make very generic things, look here http://valueinjecter.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Getting%20started&referringTitle=Home

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use a [Custom Resolver](http://automapper.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Custom%20Value%20Resolvers) that uses reflection to get all the property names and then calls your GetValue() method of the source object.

Answer (score 1):

I know this question is like 2-3 years old, but I ran into something like this and it was very hard to find the answer, mostly because IValueResolver interface is not documented in the documentation.

I ended up doing something like this:

```
public class UserProfileMapping : Profile
{
    protected override void Configure()
    {
        Mapper.CreateMap<ProfileBase, UserProfileModel>()
              .ForAllMembers(m => m.ResolveUsing<ProfileValueResolver>());
    }

    public class ProfileValueResolver : IValueResolver
    {
        public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
        {
            return source.New(
                ((ProfileBase)source.Value)
                .GetPropertyValue(source.Context.MemberName)
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps someone.